# Etymology of "di sana pianta"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

How did the term "di sana pianta" come to mean "del tutto, completamente". Where is the hidden relationship?

Comment: Ha qualcosa a che vedere con eliminare tutta la mala erba per mantenere la pianta sana?

Comment: Perché ci sono tanti voti negativi senza una spiegazione?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per pianta in architettura/edilizia si intende il disegno preliminare di ogni progetto. Quindi con "fare una cosa di sana pianta" si intende ripartire dalle fondamenta, ma anche in modo completo, radicale, come:

> Inventato di sana pianta

[Pianta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pianta/) su Traccani.it